# arr.findIndex() returns -1

Tags: arrays, redux, react-redux, find

I'm afraid it should be obvious since my affair is based on normal Vanille JS. Anyhow, for any reason I cannot get my issue fixed. Anyhone who can help me out?

Snapshot of my code in reducer:

```
> case TOGGLE_PRODUCT:
>       const newProducts = [...state.allProducts];
>       console.log("All products: ", newProducts);
>       console.log("Passed product: ", action.productId);
>       console.log("Should have found: ", newProducts[1]);
>       const toggledProduct = newProducts.findIndex(
>         (el) => el.id === action.productId
>       );
>       console.log("Found: ", toggledProduct);
```

Output in console:

```
All products:  Array [
  Product {
    "amount": 0,
    "department": "Molkereiprodukte",
    "id": "id1",
    "product": "Milch 3,5%",
    "status": false,
  },
  Product {
    "amount": 0,
    "department": "Molkereiprodukte",
    "id": "id2",
    "product": "Yoghurt",
    "status": false,
  },
  Product {
    "amount": 0,
    "department": "Ceralien",
    "id": "id3",
    "product": "Müsli",
    "status": false,
  },
]
Passed product:  Object {
  "id": "id2",
}
Should have found:  Product {
  "amount": 0,
  "department": "Molkereiprodukte",
  "id": "id2",
  "product": "Yoghurt",
  "status": false,
}
Found:  -1
```

Why does the find() method not return a result???

Thx in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `action.productId` is an `object`not a `string`

> ```
>   const toggledProduct = newProducts.findIndex(
>     (el) => el.id === action.productId.id /** <--here */
>   );
> ```

Comment: OF COURSE :-) Thank you so much for your quick response. A great occasion for me to stop working for today. Seems I'm getting blind on how to write basic code.

Answer (score 1):

`findIndex` is used to find desire index of the element you need `Array.find` to get element data. Reason you are getting `-1` is because action.productId is an object. You need to compare `action.productId.id`

```js
const toggledProduct = newProducts.find(el => el.id === action.productId.id );
```

Comment: OF COURSE :-) Thank you so much for your quick response. A great occasion for me to stop working for today. Seems I'm getting blind on how to write basic code.